# ReadTheDocs activation email not deliverd

Tags: email, read-the-docs

I tried to install ReadTheDocs on my linux server following the documentation: http://read-the-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

However I do not receive the activation email.
I was able to see the output of the email  on the server

```
Hello from example.com!

You're receiving this e-mail because you or someone else has requested a password for your user account at example.com.
It can be safely ignored if you did not request a password reset. Click the link below to reset your password.

http://xxxxx:8080/accounts/password/reset/key/xxxxxxxxxx/

In case you forgot, your username is xxxxxxxxxxxx.

Thank you for using example.com!
example.com
```

*note: This email is a password reset email, it has the same problem as the activation email. (I didn't receive any email from my ReadTheDocs installation)*

There are two things that got my attention.
1. Where does read the docs configure the website name, I would like to change example.com to th real website name.
2. The sending adres currently is no-reply@readthedocs.org, where can I change it? I think its also a part of the issue.

Here are the other headers of the email

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: [example.com] Password Reset E-mail
From: no-reply@readthedocs.org
To: xxx@xxxxx.nl
Date: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 11:30:49 -0000
```

### So actually I have two questions

- Where can I change the content of the email and things like the sender adres.
- What happend with the email (why won't I receive it)